# how does Android handle battery and CPU overheating?

Tags: aosp

Is there any internal Android mechanism for killing applications that by consuming too much CPU time cause the phone to overheat?

Comment: You might want to search for terms such as *CPU Governor*, *CPU Hotplug*, *CPU Thermal* and *Low Memory Killer*, to find relevant info.

Comment: This might help: ***[\[GUIDE\] KERNELS EXPLAINED, governors, hotplug, frequency, CPU, GPU, I/O, etc](https://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g2/help/test-t3032171)***

Comment: For an in-depth overview of the abovementioned, you can also pay a look at [this XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/general/ref-to-date-guide-cpu-governors-o-t3048957).